# How to use Vec<Bytes> as an argument for Any::decode()?

Tags: rust

I have a `Vec<Bytes>` and want to use it as an argument for `Any::decode()`.

Since `Any::decode()`'s argument is a `Buf` trait that does not require a contiguous memory, theoretically, `Vec<Bytes>` can be used without copying memory.

However, since `Vec<Bytes>` does not implement `Buf` trait, it needs to be transformed into something different.

While this scenario seems somewhat common, I failed to find an existing solution.

How might I accomplish this?

- For `Bytes` and `Buf`, see https://docs.rs/bytes/1.5.0/bytes/
- For `Any`, see https://docs.rs/prost-types/latest/prost_types/struct.Any.html
  (However, familiarity with `Any` is not necessary. all I want to know is how to use `Vec<Bytes>` as a `Buf`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [`chunked-bytes`](https://docs.rs/chunked-bytes/latest/) is useful:

```rs
use bytes::{Buf, Bytes};
use chunked_bytes::ChunkedBytes;

pub fn chain_noncopying(f: Vec<Bytes>) -> ChunkedBytes {
    f.into_iter().fold(ChunkedBytes::new(), |mut acc, b| {
        acc.put_bytes(b);
        
        acc
    })
}
```

---

old answer:

How about re-collecting into `Bytes`?:

```rs
pub fn flatten_bytes_seq(bytes_collection: Vec<Bytes>) -> Bytes {
    bytes_collection.into_iter().flatten().collect()
}
```

Comment: Since `Bytes` is a chunk of contiguous memory, the above code will involve copying memory which I don't want to do.

Comment: Hello @zeodtr, I've updated my answers. Do you think it is sufficient to satisfy your requirements?

Comment: Thank you. However, given that the `Buf` trait comprises only a few straightforward functions to implement, I might consider implementing it myself.

Answer (score 0):

If both the type (`Vec<Bytes>`) and the trait (`Buf`) are foreign, i.e. not declared by the current library, then you cannot implement the trait for the type. This is called the orphan rule in rust. https://github.com/Ixrec/rust-orphan-rules

To workaround this limitation, you use something called a [newtype pattern](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/patterns/behavioural/newtype.html).

#### NewType Pattern

You can simply declare your own custom type which will wrap the foreign type. Now, you can simply implement the foreign trait for your custom new type.

```rust
pub struct MyCustomBuf(Vec<Bytes>);

impl Buf for MyCustomBuf {
// ... impl the functions
}

// now any function that takes `impl Buf` or `T: Buf` will accept your MyCustomBuf
```

Comment: Since `Buf` implementation requires 'current position' information, a new struct (that has a `current_position` field) is required nonetheless. It would be nice if an existing implementation were available.